# Removing delimiters from bash array elements, then transferring result to another array

Tags: bash, array, options

I am using an option variable array `incl` that stores filename extensions.

```
("--incl")
      local incl+=("$2") ; shift 2 ;;
```

The function can then be called using `--incl .texi --incl .org`

But I want also to allow use of a separator `fs`

The function can then be called using `--FS ";" --incl .texi;.org`

If user is using `FS`, I need to construct an `isufx` array

```
  isufx=( '(' )
  for ext in "${incl[@]}"; do
    isufx+=( -name "*$ext" -o )
  done
  isufx[${#nmser[@]}-1]=')'
```

But first I have to separate the `fs` delimiter if they occur in tho array `${incl[@]}`.

My question involves the task of constructing `isufx` when `fs` is being used, so that I can pass `isufx` to the `find` command.

```
find "$fdir" "${isufx[@]}" ...
```

Comment: It's possibly simpler to do that when you construct the `incl` array, ex. `IFS="$fs" read -ra exts <<<"$2"; incl+=("${exts[@]}"); ...`

Comment: Would agree with that.